# Does anyone know how to find H in this question?

Tags: trigonometry

[I need to find h in this 10th grade trigonometry question. I have already found the equations for AO and BO, does anyone know the method?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xn8Ve.jpg)

Comment: Use the Pythagoras' theorem on the bottom triangle ;)

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please use [MathJax](https://www.onemathematicalcat.org/MathJaxDocumentation/TeXSyntax.htm) to format your posts.  To begin with, surround math expressions (including numbers) with `$` signs and use `_` for subscripts.  `$x_1$` comes out as $x_1$.